# Custom WYSIWYG problems with toolbar setup

Tags: tinymce, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I am working on a [custom WYSIWIG editor](https://docs.2sxc.org/js-code/custom-fields/field-wysiwyg.html) using Webcomponents and TinyMCE with [this](https://2sxc.org/dnn-tutorials/en/razor/ui242/page) as base. Testing on DNN Version 9.3.2 and 9.9.1, with 2sxc Version 11.22.1.

Problems arise when I try to use the menubutton "linkfiles" from 2sxc in the toolbar; these ADAM file management buttons don't seem work. There is also no ADAM "footer" on the editor in it's initial (inline) state. When opening the expanded editor with the "expandfulleditor" menu button the editor expands and for one uses the "default" toolbar (which I would like to change), but also the ADAM buttons work here and the ADAM "footer" is visible.

Using the base example (without any modification) this is still the case.

Is there anything I need to consider in addition to the instructions in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the example in the tutorial https://2sxc.org/dnn-tutorials/en/razor/ui242/page works - except that in the demo-mode, you cannot get the files.

I suggest you download the tutorial app and try to go from there: https://2sxc.org/en/apps/app/dnn-razor-tutorial

Note that the latest tutorial needs 2sxc 12.04 which should be released tomorrow. Otherwise get an older release.

Comment: I tried it in the tutorial now (I used 2sxc 12.02 for the 12.04 Tutorial) and have the same problem. I made the following change:
options.toolbar += " | testButton linkfiles";
adding 'linkfiles' to the toolbar at line number 46.
The same problem as described in the question occurs.

Comment: It could be a bug. I suggest you open an issue and include a demo-app with everything you did.